# How to Pass multiple array in External Api

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-api

Kindly i want to pass multiple array in external api, and get the response

I have tried but it return only one array 0 => "7200408497". instead of all array which i request

dd($idsArray)

```
array:4 [▼
            0 => "408497"
            1 => "408223"
            2 => "132116"
            3 => "408373"
            
            ]
```

My Controller

```
      public function DeviceStatus(Request $request)
    {

      $queryinput =$request->deviceNumber;
      $idsArray =explode(" ", $queryinput);
      //dd($idsArray);

      // $jsonData = [];
      foreach ($idsArray as $key=>$id) {

        try {
              $response = Http::get('http://http://127.0.0.1:8000/extapi/v12/DeviceData/ByDeviceDataSerial/'.$id.'');
              $jsonData = $response->json();
              // array_push($jsonData,$response);

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
              // toastr()->Error($exception->getMessage());
        return back()->withError($exception->getMessage());
        }
        //dd($idsArray);

        return view('tracedevice.ectsdevicestatus',compact('jsonData'));

      }
```

I need to get all array as per request

EDITED
Output after add new array in `jsonData`

```
    array:12 [▼
  7200408497 => array:4 [▼
    "payload" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:44 [▼
        "id" => 4484
        "position" => array:2 [▶]
        "mDeviceID" => "7200408497"
         "slave" => array:2 [▶]
        "payload" => ""
        "deviceDetails" => array:9 [▶]
        "isActivated" => true
        "serial" => "7200408497"
        "isDeleted" => false
        "status" => 0
      ]
      1 => array:44 [▶]
    ]
    "count" => 2
    "total" => 0
  ]
  7200408223 => array:4 [▶]
```

Comment: Don't return anything inside your `foreach` then. Create a new array with all the data needed and `return` outside of the loop

Comment: @brombeer, can you just show me example there?

Comment: Could you please try to code this yourself first? My "explanation" may be a little sparse but it should point you in the right direction. `return view('tracedevice.ectsdevicestatus',compact('jsonData'));` will step out of the `foreach` loop on the first item, so no other items will be handled.

Comment: it return the last data, because what i need to to return `response` for all data i requested there

Comment: It returns the _first_ data, not the last. I know what you want and told you what to do: store `$jsonData` in a new array (so in the end, that new array holds _all_ `$jsonData`) and when your `foreach` loop is done return the view. What are you having trouble with? Storing to a new array? Moving that `return view...` line out of your loop?

Comment: Storing to a new array and moving that `return view`

Comment: That's basic PHP knowledge. Something like `$deviceStatus[$id] = $jsonData;` will add your `$jsonData`s to an array. Then change your return line to `return view('tracedevice.ectsdevicestatus',compact('deviceStatus'));` outside of the `foreach` loop (after the last `}`). Optionally `dd($deviceStatus)` before the `return` to see what it contains. Good luck

Comment: Yes, Now it return all array,, but i have another problem here when i return in blade view i can not able to display the data  in view you can see above i edit and you can advice me how i can archive in blade view

Comment: One question/problem per post, please. If this one is resolved please post a new question with details on your new problem. Thanks

Comment: @brombeer, kindly can you advice, why it goes slow if search multiple number example 100, it goes slowly.